# Monotouch: Table report

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have to create a function to create table reports in runtime, the function will receive the columns names and the rows values so this function only have to create a table with  the data and then show it in the UI.

I saw that UITableView only have one column and I have to create n number of columns, so my question is, What kind of control can I use? Of course I need to be able to scroll in horizontal and vertical ways.

I'm using motouch dialog in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Monotouch.Dialog is recommend only for trivial forms. What you're describing isn't trivial even in iOS...

If you really need to use MT Dialog, you can put your form inside a scroll view (horizontal scroll only) then set the scroll view's content size and the form's width to match the size of your columns. After this, to implement "columns" in your table view, just put the column headers in the table view header and in each row use a custom cell with n subviews to your n columns.

But, if you can put MT dialog apart, I'm sure that have at last one component on github to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: thanks, I will look for a component in github and make a search about how I can create a custom cell who create n number of subviews to simulate the columns.

The 99% of my app is formed by trivial forms thats why I use MT.D and a UINavigationController, so if it's possible, I don't have problem with use other controls for the reports. And also more of 90% of my app is  created  dynamically accord to a requeriments file.  

I started with monotouch 2 weeks ago, I know few things about IOS development.